# Integrated Chicony webcam not found after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: 22.04, lenovo, webcam

No luck getting webcam to work on Lenovo Legion 5 after upgrade to 22.04, with Cheese giving error `No device found`.
Have tried various approaches from various threads and getting nowhere.
Here's output from `lsusb`

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 048d:c100 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. ITE Device(8910)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 048d:c955 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. ITE Device(8295)
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And from `sudo dmesg | grep -i camera`

```
[    2.370159] usb 1-6: Found UVC 1.10 device Integrated Camera (04f2:b6c2)
[    2.373908] input: Integrated Camera: Integrated C as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/input/input8
[   23.351703] usb 1-6: Product: Integrated Camera
[   23.354370] usb 1-6: Found UVC 1.10 device Integrated Camera (04f2:b6c2)
[   23.358045] input: Integrated Camera: Integrated C as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/input/input28
[   39.224749] usb 1-6: Product: Integrated Camera
[   39.228352] usb 1-6: Found UVC 1.10 device Integrated Camera (04f2:b6c2)
[   39.234084] input: Integrated Camera: Integrated C as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/input/input29
[ 1897.536700] usb 1-6: Product: Integrated Camera
[ 1897.539238] usb 1-6: Found UVC 1.10 device Integrated Camera (04f2:b6c2)
[ 1897.542602] input: Integrated Camera: Integrated C as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/input/input30
[ 1938.328692] usb 1-6: Product: Integrated Camera
[ 1938.332214] usb 1-6: Found UVC 1.10 device Integrated Camera (04f2:b6c2)
[ 1938.336050] input: Integrated Camera: Integrated C as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/input/input31
[ 2070.684482] usb 1-6: Product: Integrated Camera
[ 2070.687167] usb 1-6: Found UVC 1.10 device Integrated Camera (04f2:b6c2)
[ 2070.690612] input: Integrated Camera: Integrated C as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/input/input32
[ 3044.293355] usb 1-6: Product: Integrated Camera
[ 3044.295929] usb 1-6: Found UVC 1.10 device Integrated Camera (04f2:b6c2)
[ 3044.299579] input: Integrated Camera: Integrated C as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/input/input33
[ 3102.341026] usb 1-6: Product: Integrated Camera
[ 3102.343771] usb 1-6: Found UVC 1.10 device Integrated Camera (04f2:b6c2)
[ 3102.347361] input: Integrated Camera: Integrated C as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/input/input34
[ 4186.488517] usb 1-6: Product: Integrated Camera
[ 4186.493744] usb 1-6: Found UVC 1.10 device Integrated Camera (04f2:b6c2)
[ 4186.499515] input: Integrated Camera: Integrated C as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/input/input35
[ 4187.547467] usb 1-6: Product: Integrated Camera
[ 4187.550096] usb 1-6: Found UVC 1.10 device Integrated Camera (04f2:b6c2)
[ 4187.553947] input: Integrated Camera: Integrated C as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/input/input36
```

And from `lsmod|grep uvcvideo`

```
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_v4l2         32768  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       77824  4 videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_memops
videodev              258048  7 videobuf2_v4l2,v4l2loopback,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mc                     65536  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you have enabled your camera (keyboard shortcuts, physical switch) if that does not work try updating your BIOS and packages on ubuntu. Please share you exact model of legion 5, I have legion 5 myself and my webcam is working perfectly fine after I upgraded to 22.04.

Comment: Hi -- am on a 151MH0%H. Physical switch is on, and can't see a keyboard shortcut for turning on/off webcam. Have done an ```apt full-upgrade```, will take a look and see if I can update the BIOS. Any other thoughts much appreciated.